# Application-specific Permission Settings

Tags: windows-10, permissions

On a **Windows 10 Pro** system with all the latest patches I'm getting a lot of errors with **Event Id 10016**. An example:

- > The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
  >   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
  >   {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}  and APPID 
  >   {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}  to the user COLOSSUS\Slacker
  >   SID (S-1-5-21-550145320-736483266-2972815005-1001) from address
  >   LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container
  >   Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be
  >   modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

I've come across advice that directs me to use regedit to change the permissions on the items with corresponding keys. When I try to do that, I'm denied the ability to make changes.

Also, the permissions dialog has an entry I've never seen before when it comes up, listing an "`Account Unknown(S-1-15-3...`". I can't remove that account, either.

**Question:** How do I go about changing the permissions to eliminate the 10016 errors, or is it okay to ignore them?

**Note:** I don't remember seeing them crop up until relatively recently (e.g., perhaps after the Spring 2018 update).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per Microsoft, you should ***just ignore these 10016 Event IDs*** and it is ***not recommended*** to try to fix through manipulating security of objects and such to circumvent as these occur by design. In the **Workaround** section there's an XML filtering query method for advanced users to suppress.

> ### Safely Ignore these Event IDs 10016
>
> The specific points and to those points [per the vendor Microsoft for
>   the 10016 Event
>   ID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022522/dcom-event-id-10016-is-logged-in-windows-10-and-windows-server-2016).
>   . .
>
> - > *"These events can be safely ignored because they do not adversely
>   >     affect functionality and are by design. This is the recommend action
>   >     for these events."*
>   >
>   > ---
> - > *"You can also work around this issue by modifying the permissions on DCOM components to prevent this error from being logged. However,
>   >     we
>   >     do not recommend this method because these errors do not adversely
>   >     affect functionality and modifying the permissions can have unintended
>   >     side effects."*

---

> ### [**DCOM event ID 10016 is logged in Windows**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022522/dcom-event-id-10016-is-logged-in-windows-10-and-windows-server-2016)
>
> **Symptoms**
>
> <sub>**Applies to:** *Windows 10, version 1909 Windows
>   Server, version 1909 (Datacenter, Standard) Windows 10, version 1903
>   Windows Server, version 1903 Windows 10, version 1809 Windows Server
>   2019, all versions Windows Server version 1803 Windows 10, version
>   1803 Windows 10, version 1709 Windows 10, version 1703 Windows 10,
>   version 1607 Windows Server 2016 Standard Windows Server 2016
>   Datacenter Windows Server 2016 Standard edition Nano Server
>   installation option Windows Server 2016 Datacenter edition Nano Server
>   installation option Windows Server 2016 Essentials*</sub>
>
> > ***Application-specific Permission Settings Related Events***
> >
> > ```
> > Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM
> > Event ID:      10016
> >
> > Description: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission 
> > for the COM Server application with CLSID {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160} and APPID
> > {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276} to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from 
> > address LocalHost (using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). 
> > This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
> > ```
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ```
> > Description: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission 
> > for the COM Server application with CLSID {260EB9DE-5CBE-4BFF-A99A-3710AF55BF1E} and APPID
> > {260EB9DE-5CBE-4BFF-A99A-3710AF55BF1E} to the user machine\user SID (S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx) 
> > from address LocalHost (using LRPC) running in the application container 
> > Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.14393.726_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
> > SID (S-1-15-2-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx).
> > This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
> > ```
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ```
> > Description: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission 
> > for the COM Server application with CLSID {6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52} and APPID
> > {4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D} to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) 
> > from address LocalHost (using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). 
> > This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
> > ```
>
> ---
>
> **Cause**
>
> These 10016 events are recorded when Microsoft components tries to
>   access DCOM components without the required permissions. In this case,
>   this is expected and by design.
>
> A coding pattern has been implemented where the code first tries to
>   access the DCOM components with one set of parameters. If the first
>   attempt is unsuccessful, it tries again with another set of
>   parameters. The reason why it does not skip the first attempt is
>   because there are scenarios where it can succeed. ***In those
>   scenarios,*** ***that is preferable***.
>
> ---
>
> **Workaround**
>
> *These events can be safely ignored because they do not adversely affect functionality and are by design. This is the recommend action
>   for these events.*
>
> If desired, advanced users and IT professionals can suppress these
>   events from view in the Event Viewer by creating a filter and manually
>   editing the filter’s XML query similar to the following:
>
> ```
> <QueryList>
>   <Query Id="0" Path="System">
>     <Select Path="System">*</Select>
>     <Suppress Path="System">
>       *[System[(EventID=10016)]]
>       and
>       *[EventData[
>         (
>           Data[@Name='param4'] and Data='{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}' and
>           Data[@Name='param5'] and Data='{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}'
>         ) 
>         or
>         (
>           Data[@Name='param4'] and Data='{260EB9DE-5CBE-4BFF-A99A-3710AF55BF1E}' and
>           Data[@Name='param5'] and Data='{260EB9DE-5CBE-4BFF-A99A-3710AF55BF1E}'
>         ) 
>         or
>         (
>           Data[@Name='param4'] and Data='{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}' and
>           Data[@Name='param5'] and Data='{316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}'
>         )
>         or
>         (
>           Data[@Name='param4'] and Data='{6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52}' and
>           Data[@Name='param5'] and Data='{4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D}'
>         ) 
>         or
>         (
>           Data[@Name='param4'] and Data='{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}' and
>           Data[@Name='param5'] and Data='{316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}'
>         )
>       ]]
>     </Suppress>
>   </Query>
> </QueryList>
> ```
>
> In this query, param4 corresponds to the COM Server application CLSID
>   and param5 corresponds to the APPID which are recorded in the 10016
>   event logs.
>
> For more information about manually constructing Event Viewer queries,
>   see [Advanced XML filtering in the Windows Event
>   Viewer](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer/).
>
> *You can also work around this issue by modifying the permissions on DCOM components to prevent this error from being logged. However, we
>   do not recommend this method because these errors do not adversely
>   affect functionality and modifying the permissions can have unintended
>   side effects.*
>
> [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022522/dcom-event-id-10016-is-logged-in-windows-10-and-windows-server-2016)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a 100% fix but I had to share it.  You can read the lengthy description of it in this thread. The error you seeing is likely to be a symptom of this.

[Source thread on tenforums.com](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/109079-event-id-10016-distributedcom-windows-securitycenter-wscbrokermanager-post1459960.html#post1459960)

And the tl;dr fix:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wscsvc  

Change the DWORD DelayedAutoStart from 1 to 0.
```